# Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535 when SSH using AD Creds on RHEL Machine

Tags: linux, active-directory, ssh, pam

Recently I installed PAM & all the necessary packages needed to enable ssh authentication via AD on my RHEL 7.5 machines.

When I try to SSH using "ssh user@domainname@hostname" it asks for my password and as soon as I type my password, I get the error: Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535.

This happens on several machines running RHEL 7.5. sssd is used to bind to AD, there are no firewalls, system time is in sync with AD server, appropriate groups are added to permitted_groups, and the account is not locked out. Tailing the /var/log/secure shows the errors below:

```
sshd[12752]: reprocess config line 145: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
sshd[12752]: pam_krb5[12752]: account checks fail for 'user@domainname': user disallowed by .k5login file for 'user@domainname'
sshd[12752]: Failed password for user@domainname from ip port 53166 ssh2
sshd[12752]: fatal: Access denied for user user@domainname by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

I have restarted sssd and sshd without any luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First, using pam_krb5 instead of pam_sss is not a good idea. Second, as the messages say, you seem to have a .k5login file in this user's home directory that doesn't contian this user's UPN.

Comment: is there a way to migrate from pam_krb5 to pam_sss?

Comment: seen this when my proxy command closed stdin and exited by itself

Comment: @akostadinov so, is it a benign message? Can we configure the proxy server to be aware of this and not give such a cryptic message ? Thank you !

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă, `ProxyCommand` in the sense of `man ssh`. It is usually another `ssh` command. wrt improvements to error message, I think you better file a bug request in upstream `sshd` project.

Answer (score 19):

The super-unhelpful ssh error `Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535` can be reported when your `ssh` client in a couple of different situations when the remote `sshd` cannot be reached at all because of something happening "in the middle".

This can be extra-tricky to debug because **in some cases** the remote sshd has no idea that anyone is ever tried to connect to it.

(Aside 65535 is "special" number to computer folks as it is `2^16 - 1`, aka `0xFFF` -- the maximum unsigned 16 bit integer (also the max port number))

**Case A --** (From @doug 's original question) - In this case the remote sshd got the incoming connection and delegated auth down to Linux libraries for PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules).  PAM hands off to KRB5 or SSS and that fails.  So all the poor remote sshd gets is a big *NOPE* from PAM. ...it never got into it's "normal" protocol parsing and error checking that would let it return a more helpful error message.

(It's *possible* that old Kerberos config options like gssapiauthentication might behave similarly)

**Case B --** In our case we saw this when network firewalls prevented connections from the dev/test machines to staging/production machines.
Depending on your network, you might be able get more diagnostics info with `tcping $remote_hostname 22`, or (less helpful): UDP network tests like `ping $remote_hostname`, `traceroute $remote_hostname`, or the IPv6 versions of those commands.  Your local network engineers can help confirm & fix.

The giveaway in this case is that `ssh -vvv $remote_hostname` gets to this point:

```
debug1: identity file /home/ddickinson/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
```

...pauses for 60s (or whatever timeout), then:

```
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

**Case C --** Some kinds of failures of the `ProxyCommand` that your local `ssh` delegates to can also fail in unhelpful ways.  Check for any "proxy*" or "tunnel*" related options in the output of:

```
ssh -G $remote_hostname
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me realize that the `ProxyCommand` I was using for a particular `Host <ip>` section caused this failure for me.